# What's the correct way to add custom CSS to Gutenberg Editor

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to find the correct way to add custom CSS to the WordPress Gutenberg editor. Currently, I have added a custom .CSS file to my child-theme CSS directory and added the following function to the child-theme's function.php file.

```
    // Custom Editor Styles
    function theme_editor_styles() {
        // Add support for Editor Styles
        add_theme_support('editor-styles');

        // Enqueue Editor Styles
        add_editor_style('style-editor.css');
    }

    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_editor_styles');
```

However, when I refresh the WordPress editor, nothing has changed. I have added a background-color of black to the body property so when the file loads it's obvious.

Is the above function incorrect or am I trying to do this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs when the Parent Theme does not have `add_theme_support('editor-styles')`  declared. The Child Theme is unable to override an option or stylesheet the Parent Theme does not include (ref: [Advanced Topics / Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php) )

To resolve this issue, simply locate the function in the Parent Theme functions.php which hooks into `add_action('after_setup_theme', ...)`,  then remove it via your Child Theme and add your own function which supports editor styles, eg:

Child Theme: functions.php

```
// Custom Editor Styles
function theme_editor_styles() {
    // Add support for Editor Styles
    add_theme_support('editor-styles');

    // Enqueue Editor Styles
    add_editor_style('style-editor.css');

   // Also re-add any other add_theme_support() options as needed from Parent Theme
}

// Remove the Parent Themes Editor Styles function
remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'name_of_parent_theme_editor_styles' );
// Add your own Editor Styles to add support for Guternberg Editor Styles
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_editor_styles' );
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The only way to get the styles to load is by commenting out `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twenty_twenty_one_setup' );` in the parent theme. Any idea why this might be?